# iPad app interface orientation changed after launch of aplicaiton

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

i am working on app. the orientation of app is landscape but after app run interface orientation of app change the interface and rotate. splash screen display in correct way (landscape).
i am using ios7 the app was code for ios5 i think there is some deprecated api issue e.g. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation bot called because this is no more available in latest ios

[image]

Comment: You want to show this view in landscape?

Comment: yes deepak as you se my app orientation is rotated but the simulator is in landscape mode . my app is also for landscape

Comment: Check orientation of your XIB view in attributes inspector..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of our navigation controllers to respect the top view controller you can use a category so you don't have to go through and change a bunch of class names.

```
 @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
 } 

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject]     preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

As a few of the comments point to, this is a quick fix to the problem. A better solution is subclass UINavigationController and put these methods there. A subclass also helps for supporting 6 and 7.

Comment: my app just for iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you have to set orintatoin in build seeting see image.

it will solve your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

**EDIT :**

See the attached [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zw3qesn8w4v66hy/Archive.zip), might be helpful for you.

Comment: Is this your first View?

Answer (score 0):

i find solution the think which i do is.
step one 
override my UInavigationcontroller by creating a category

step two 
Replace
[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];  //OLD

With
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];  //NEW

Answer (score 0):

use this in your Appdelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSLog(@"Interface orientations");
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ){

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandScape;
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

It helped me..