# iOS 7 Force Portrait Orientation When Dismissing Push

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

At this time I am halfway to keeping ViewControllerA in portrait mode.  To do this, I am using **preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation**

This ensures that ViewControllerA, when I push to it, will be in portrait mode.  However, if I push from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB, switch to landscape mode in ViewControllerB, **and then dismiss back to ViewControllerA, ViewControllerA can be presented in landscape mode.  My desire is to continue multiple orientation support of ViewControllerB, but force ViewControllerA to autorotate to portrait.**

Also, for some reason **shouldAutorotate** does not appear to be getting called in ViewControllerA.  Perhaps addressing this could fix the entire issue?

UINavigationController+Orientation.h Category

```
@interface UINavigationController (Orientation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;

@end
```

UINavigationController+Orientation.m Category

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to get things working!

So one thing in my situation that was making things difficult was I had two segments; one took place before logging in (did not have NavController) an the other was post login (did have NavController).  Perhaps I broke a best practice guideline there?

Anyways, Teo C.'s answer is the one that helped me: [iOS 7. Change page orientation only for one view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905088/ios-7-change-page-orientation-only-for-one-view-controller)

I made this discovery by making a new blank project.  If you are having trouble with forcing orientations, you can look at the example I made https://github.com/jerherrero/Force-Orientations

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. My solution is below, and its in a released app.

I added a public property called allowViewRotation to my AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL allowViewRotation;
```

Then I've implemented the following call in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { // if iPad
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

    if (self.allowViewRotation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Now in ViewControllerA set allowViewRotation property to NO

```
((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).allowViewRotation = NO;
```

And in ViewControllerB set allowViewRotation property to YES

```
((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).allowViewRotation = YES;
```

Note: make sure that you enable the proper device orientation in Deployment Info

[image]

hope this helps!

Comment: It still does not seem to be working.  And I am using the same orientation settings as you did (all but upside-down).  I tried using **((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).allowViewRotation** in both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, but both did not prevent ViewControllerA from loading as landscape upon dismissing back to it.

Comment: make sure the default is allowViewRotation=NO. and put the YES/NO changing inside of ViewControllerB's **viewWillAppear:** and **viewWillDisappear:** `-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    appDelegate.allowViewRotation = YES;
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    appDelegate.allowViewRotation = NO;
}`

Comment: try to call attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation to force the app to call **supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow**  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIViewController/attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation

Comment: Thanks for the all quick replies!  I tried to call **attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation**, but again to no avail.  As for **viewWillAppear** and *viewWillDisappear**, I have tried the setup you mentioned, along with variations of it.  Yet it doesn't seem to be going through.  If ViewControllerA is in landscape (which I don't want), it will switch to portrait if the phone is moved into that orientation and then lock it from there.  But that is currently as close as I can get it.

Comment: yea, there used to be a call to UIDevice to force orientation change, but it was a private call and recently in iOS7 its no longer there. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.